# How can I pass a constant value for 1 binding in multi-binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, multibinding

I have a multi-binding like

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
            <Binding Path="myFirst.Value" />
            <Binding Path="mySecond.Value" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

And I want to pass a fixed value e.g. "123" to one of the two bindings above. How can I do that using XAML?

Comment: any code snippets/examples please?

Comment: I think some part of the question is missing, you are refering to binding above but I don't see any binding code in the question.

Comment: Somehow each time I have a question someone had the exactly same question previously :) Great!

Comment: A fourth way to do this would be to use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2552911/222134

Answer (score 176, accepted):

If your value is simply a `string`, you can specify it as a constant in the `Source` property of a binding. If it is any other primitive data type, you need to define a static resource and reference this.

Define the `sys` namespace in the root of the XAML to point to `System` in mscorlib, and the following should work:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Resources>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="fixedValue">123</sys:Int32>
  </TextBlock.Resources>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
      <Binding Path="myFirst.Value" />
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource fixedValue}" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: @tofutim That's because MultiBinding doesn't seem to have Resources. Use TextBlock.Resources instead...

Comment: Maybe you should add xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" to your solution ;-)

Answer (score 125):

Or, combining the two answers above:

Define the namespace sys at the document head:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and then:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ScalingConverter}">
    <Binding>
        <Binding.Source>
            <sys:Double>0.5</sys:Double>
        </Binding.Source>
    </Binding>
    <Binding ElementName="TC" Path="ActualWidth" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Which provides the right type without the Resources kludge.

Comment: It's needed to define the namespace `sys` at the document head: ```xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"```

Answer (score 32):

I don't quite follow the question but there are two options:

Put the line `<Binding Source="123" />` in your multibinding will pass 123 as a bound value to your converter.

Put `ConverterParameter="123"` in your MultiBinding:

`<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}" ConverterParameter="123">`

Comment: <Binding Source="123" /> seems to pass DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

Comment: <Binding Source="123" /> passes the string "123" instead of the integer or double that I intended in my case.

Comment: In `IValueConverter`, the parameters are passed as `object`, which means you would need cast the value to the correct type, in a safe way. [IValueConverter.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not saying this an especially good answer but here is another approach:

```
<Binding Path="DoesNotExist" FallbackValue="123" />
```