# Convert text to MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I have a problem trying to convert existing XAML to MultiBinding.
The current code (which needs to be replaced) is

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding BarcodeCollection.Count}" />
<TextBlock  Text="{x:Static p:Resource.AllWN}" />
```

What I have now:

```
<control:MyControl>
    <control:MyControl.ControlText>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="BarcodeCollection.Count"/> <!-- This part works fine -->
            <Binding ??? /> <!-- No idea how to re-write this part -->
        </MultiBinding>
    </control:MyControl.ControlText>
</control:MyControl>
```

I tried many things I could think of to make the 2nd part working but couldn't figure it out. I tried using `Path` but it's *not* a path so obviously it didn't work. I also tried all kinds of variations through `StringFormat`, `Source` & `RelativeSource` but nothing seemed to work.

Anyone have any ideas? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set **`Source`** like this:

```
<Binding Source="{x:Static p:Resource.AllWN}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why my usage of `Source` didn't worked out in the first place but you now saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 1):

According to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/3341536/1157021 the source should work in this form:

```
<Binding Source="{StaticResource p:Resource.AllWN}" />
```

Comment: This won't work because for this resource has to be defined in XAML. But OP is binding it with static value from ViewModel.