# Binding multiple textbox colors with conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have multiple textboxes in my application. I would like to change the border of the textboxes to green or blue depending on the number the user has entered.

I can bind the values of a text box and use IValueConverter to convert double to color. This works fine.

The problem is that I have multiple textboxes with different conditions. Is there a way to define a general conversion function and specify the conditions elsewhere? What I have in mind is a boolean variable that changes depending on the value of each textbox. This variable can then be used for the conversion of the textbox border color.

Comment: you should probably include some code for reference purposes; but ,yes, it's possible  - in the sense that you can use delegates (Func or Action) on a collection, where the collection is `Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(Func<TextBox,bool>)`.. you're essentially just enumerating over instances that satisfy a condition from a 'previous' enumeration (though, in this manner, it may be optimized to not actually perform two iterations over a collection)..

Answer (score 0):

You could use I**Multi**ValueConverter with the compare operator (maybe as string) for the Converter 'Parameter' and a fixed Value as one of the bindings.
Have a look at

[How can I pass a constant value for 1 binding in multi-binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340821/how-can-i-pass-a-constant-value-for-1-binding-in-multi-binding)

how to pass constant value for Binding.