# WPF binding to two properties

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a WPF control that has a `Message` property.

I currently have this:

```
 <dxlc:LayoutItem >
            <local:Indicator Message="{Binding PropertyOne}" />
 </dxlc:LayoutItem>
```

But i need that `Message` property to be bound to two properties.

Obviously can't be done like this, but this can help explain what it is I want:

```
<dxlc:LayoutItem >
            <local:Indicator Message="{Binding PropertyOne && Binding PropertyTwo}" />
 </dxlc:LayoutItem>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2552853/1518546

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try use the [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Describes a collection of Binding objects attached to a single binding target property.

Example:

`XAML`

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}"
                     ConverterParameter="FormatLastFirst">
          <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
          <Binding Path="LastName"/>
       </MultiBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

`Converter`

```
public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string name;

        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "FormatLastFirst":
                name = values[1] + ", " + values[0];
                break;
            case "FormatNormal":
                default:
                name = values[0] + " " + values[1];
                break;
        }

        return name;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] splitValues = ((string)value).Split(' ');
        return splitValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a horribly verbose way to achieve this.

Answer (score 44):

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
        <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
        <Binding Path="LastName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: simply the best!!

Comment: How to format some string binding? I have field `TimeSpan` then `<Binding Path="TotalTime" StringFormat="hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff"/>` but it not work

Answer (score 8):

You can't do `And` operation in XAML.

Create wrapper property in your view model class which will return and of two properties and bind with that property instead.

```
public bool UnionWrapperProperty
{
   get
   {
      return PropertyOne && PropertyTwo;
   }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<local:Indicator Message="{Binding UnionWrapperProperty}" />
```

---

Another approach would be to use **`MultiValueConverter`**. Pass two properties to it and return And value from the converter instead.

Comment: What you have posted isn't a `Bitwise AND`. It's just an `AND` operator. In any case, I think he wanted whatever the type is, concatenated.

Comment: Yeah. But OP haven't mentioned anything in question and since we can't `&&` strings (or all types). So, was just assuming OP wants bool property. Will update once OP clears the picture.