# Binding a bool property to a bool expression

Tags: wpf, xaml, boolean, boolean-expression

I have some xaml (for example: `<Button IsEnabled="{Binding enableButton}"/>`) and I want to bind it to two bools (for instance, `enableButton` and `alsoEnableButton`) such that `button.IsEnabled = enableButton && alsoEnableButton;`, but I want to do this entirely in the xaml. I've seen this question that looks very similar to what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to apply it for my specific situation: [WPF binding to two properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225751/wpf-binding-to-two-properties) - this question addresses setting properties that are not boolean, I want to put a boolean expression in the xaml (ex `<Button IsEnabled="true || false"/>` or something like that).

How do I bind a xaml property to a boolean expression? Is this possible?

Comment: i think, you cannot, you will need a property with custom getter in your view model

Comment: You can't do it entirely in XAML. You can `&&` the bools in your viewmodel, or in a multivalueconverter. You linked an answer to this question. When you tried to apply that answer to doing the exact same thing but with bools, where did you run into trouble?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I know it's *very* similar to that question (please re-read my question, I state it as such). But it's not a duplicate

Comment: The difference between concatenating two strings and anding two booleans is not that great, even if you do have to cast them all from objects beforehand.

Comment: Yes, work on your abstraction skills, this is most definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Not my dv btw. I tried to find the same feature myself a few years ago.

Comment: @H.B. If this *was* a duplicate, then it would result in the same answer. Obviously it's possible with multiple binding in the other case, but not in this case. This is going to result in a different answer (even if that answer is "it's not possible")

Comment: @H.B. Please answer the question and tell me how, then. Because the answer available here isn't working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225751/wpf-binding-to-two-properties

Comment: See my concatenation vs `and` comment above. Cast the parameters to bool and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: You can also use a `MultiTrigger` by the way. (Only works for ANDing bindings i think.)