# How to use StringFormat to format a text in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to format display the following text using `StringFormat` in XAML, but I don't know where to enter the "Current Temperature: " string here:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TempText, StringFormat={"Current Temperature: "}{0}°C}"
```

The final output should be:

```
Current Temperature: 10°C
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552853/how-to-bind-multiple-values-to-a-single-wpf-textblock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code gives you the required output.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TempText, StringFormat='Current Temperature: {0} &#186; C'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use MultiBinding along with StringFormat

this msdn may help:

"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx"