# c# wpf Multibindings not aviable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, multibinding

what i want to do is quite simple. I have got a Window and I Want the Title to be bound to two different Properties. The Title should be Updated everytime one of the Properties changes.

What I tried first *and didnt work*

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="{Binding Path=Clientname} {Binding Path=LoadedConfiguration}"
```

So then I read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552853/how-to-bind-multiple-values-to-a-single-wpf-textblock) about Multibindings. And tried its usage like this *what actually doesnt work, too*

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Window.Title>
    <Multibinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
        <Binding Path="Clientname" />
        <Binding Path="LoadedConfiguration" />
    </Multibinding>
</Window.Title>
```

The Error ist that **Multibinding is not supported in a WPF project**, what in my opinion doesnt make any sense.

So, what im guessing is a missing xmlns or a missing .dll. I found out that Multibindings are inside *"PresentationFramework.dll"*, which i have referenced. According to msdn, you need either *http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation* or *http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation* to include, which I did.

Here I may actually not get any further, I hope you get.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `MultiBinding`, not `Multibinding`.
XAML is case sensitive.

Comment: Cannot believe this solved my issue, funny *MultiBinding* is still not choseable in Intellisense, like other Classes like *TextBlock* are.  - Anyway **Thanks alot**