# MultiBinding in a Tag is returning null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I am trying to pass many bindings in a button tag but I'm receiving an null result in its tag.  Here is the code:

```
<Button Click="ViewDanfSingle"  VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Margin="0 -4 0 0"  Grid.Column="1"  Style="{StaticResource buttonTransparent}">
    <Button.Tag>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
             <Binding Path="XmlSequencia"/>
             <Binding Path="NfesaiChaveAcesso"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.Tag>
</Button>
```

Here is the code where I receive the Tag value:

```
private void ViewDanfSingle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Button btn =  (Button)sender;
     string mytag =  btn.Tag.ToString();
}
```

the Model is this follow

```
public class NfeSaida
{
    #region Constantes

    public const int TamanhoMaximoChaveAcesso = 44;
    public const int TamanhoMaximoRazaoNome = 60;
    public const int TamanhoMaximoNomeFantasia = 60;

    #endregion



        #region Propriedades

    public int NfesaiSequencia { get; set; }
    public int? EmpSequencia { get; set; }
    public int? EdnfeSequenciaDest { get; set; }
    public int? XmlSequencia { get; set; }
    public int UsuSequenciaInclusao
        #endregion

}
```

But in my code the Tag property is returning  null
am I doing something wrog? I am  basing my code [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552853/how-to-bind-multiple-values-to-a-single-wpf-textblock)

Comment: You are probably trying to read locally set value, which is not set. Try to read binding value instead.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get right, in this case both  values are set, the problems seems to be when i am using the multbiding cause when I use tag="{biding path=something}" it works but I can pass more then one value in this way

Comment: Could you show the lines of code where the Tag property is returned as null?

Comment: i just update the code, not it's not showing any error mensage

Comment: *"it's not showing any error mensage"* - it does, you have to look into "Output" window to see it.

Comment: There should be something like *System.Windows.Data Error: 31 : Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be specified.*

Comment: Well, as @Sinatr said bellow it's cause Tag is object and not string so the solution was to get the biding from the textBlock, Thank you  guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you are referencing will only work with properties of `string` type, e.g. `TextBlock.Text`.

For other types ([`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) is `object`) you will have to use a converter ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2552868/1997232) answer uses it) or another approach.

---

One possibility is to *proxy* output using something what is working ;)

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="hiddenText">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
            <Binding Path="XmlSequencia" />
            <Binding Path="NfesaiChaveAcesso" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text></TextBlock>
<!-- use collapsed textblock to generate content for button tag -->
<Button Tag="{Binding Text, ElementName=hiddenText}" Click="ViewDanfSingle" />
```

Comment: Thank  you  it worked just properly the second option worked fine, the  first one didn't work