# Binding all elements of ObservableCollection to TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, textblock

I am trying to bind a TextBlock to items in a ObservableCollection. TextBlock values should be generated up to elements from collection. Count of elements in collection is between 0 and 7 (if it helps). MyClass implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. It should be directly TextBlock, not ListBox. How can I do it? Thanks!

Update: The problem is that I don't know previously the number of elements in collection. I know that it is better to use ListBox or ListView in this case, but it's important to make it in TextBlock or Label

For example:

1. ObservableCollection contains elements 0, 1, 2.
   TextBlock should contains following "Values: 0, 1, 2"
2. ObservableCollection contains elements 0, 1.
   TextBlock should contains following "Values: 0, 1"

   ```
   <TextBlock>
          <Run Text="Values: "/>
          <Run Text="{Binding Values}" />                 
   </TextBlock>
   ```

```
ObservableCollection<int> values = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        public ObservableCollection<int> Values
        {
            get => values;
            set
            {
                values = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind multiple values to a single WPF TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552853/how-to-bind-multiple-values-to-a-single-wpf-textblock)

Comment: @MikeT I don't think it's a duplicate of provided link. The question is about binding several entries from ObservableCollection not several values from one single entry in collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Converter that concat those strings:

```
public class StringsCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return string.Join("\n", value as ObservableCollection<string>);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringsCollectionConverter x:Key="StringsCollectionConverter"/>
</Window.Resources> 
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBlockCollection, Converter={StaticResource StringsCollectionConverter}}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The problem is, that if collection be changed, the Text will be not updated.

Comment: Yes It will, make sure to use TwoWay Binding, Implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface and call  OnPropertyChanged("TextBlockCollection"); after the collection Is Changed

Comment: I mean that if the same collection have one more item.

Comment: I am not following ?

Comment: Will Text be updated, if new items will be added to the collection?

Comment: Even if you call OnPropertyChanged("TextBlockCollection", if collection changed __and collection remains the same object__, the bound property will be not updated.

Comment: No, Calling OnPropertyChanged will force the TextBlock To rerender It self

Comment: If you want to check that just try it out, add a button or something!  `private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlockCollection[0] = "Updated";
            OnPropertyChanged("TextBlockCollection");
        }` 
And pls don't downvote unless you are sure that the answer is totally worthless !

Comment: You are right! My apologizes! I undo my down vote(but you need probably change you answer for it works)

Comment: Disadvantage is, that you have to put OnPropertyChanged("TextBlockCollection") everywhere you modify the collection.

Comment: I agree, after all this is a working solution, a fancier one would be to handle the CollectionChanged event!

Comment: To make it more clear it would be good to paste an example with adding a value and calling OnPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to the collection using a converter.
The problem is to get value updated on collection changed(here I mean not setting Values to new collection, but adding/removing items to/from the collection).
To implement updating on add/remove you have to use `MultiBinding` with one of bindings to the ObservableCollection.Count, so if the count be changed, then the bound property will be updated.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultValConverter x:Key="multivalcnv"/>
</Window.Resources> 
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multivalcnv}">
            <Binding Path="Values"/>
            <Binding Path="Values.Count"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>

public class MultValConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length > 1 && values[0] is ICollection myCol)
        {
            var retVal = string.Empty;
            var firstelem = true;
            foreach (var item in myCol)
            {
                retVal += $"{(firstelem?string.Empty:", ")}{item}";
                firstelem = false;
            }

            return retVal;
        }
        else
            return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("It's a one way converter.");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a MultiBinding here !

Comment: With MultiBinding I don't need to do something in VewModel (No NotifyPropertyChanged) on each collection modification.

Comment: You didn't use values[1], why passing it then !

Comment: For `MultiBinding` updates target, if `Count` changed.

Answer (score 0):

create an additional string property, which will change every time when collection item[s] change:

```
public class Vm
{
    public Vm()
    { 
       // new collection assigned via property because property setter adds event handler
       Values = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }

    ObservableCollection<int> values;
    public ObservableCollection<int> Values
    {
        get => values;
        set
        {
            if (values != null) values.CollectionChanged -= CollectionChangedHandler;
            values = value;
            if (values != null) values.CollectionChanged += CollectionChangedHandler;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void CollectionChangedHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("ValuesText");
    }

    public string ValuesText
    {
        get { return "Values: " + String.Join(", ", values);}
    }
}
```

and then bind to that property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ValuesText}"/>
```

Comment: It's definitely an option to handle all in ViewModel. The question is where does it better belong to (View or ViewModel)?

Comment: @Rekshino, VM. there is for example entire ReactiveUI framework, which uses such properties left and right: see [Output Properties](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/),  [another example](http://pasoft-sharereactiveui.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics/to-property/)