# Is it possible to use classical converter with parameters in MultiBinding QuickConverter in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, parameter-passing, converters, multibinding

Is it possible to use classical converter with parameters with QuickConverter MultiBinding in WPF ?

More clearly, I want to bind the Text property of a TextBlock to display a text like this :

```
<MyApplication> + ' v' + <1.0>
```

`MyApplication` comes from a string resource `Resources.String225` and `1.0` might comes from an `IValueConverter` class type to which I may pass the parameter `myParameter` .
I tried the XAML code below,

```
<TextBlock Text="{qc:MultiBinding '$V0 + \' v\' + $V1',
 V0={x:Static resx:Resources.String225},
 V1={Binding Converter={StaticResource ProgramVersionConverter}, ConverterParameter='myParameter'}}"/>
```

With the following Converter :

```
public class ProgramVersionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static Func<string, string> GetApplicationExeVersion;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns version of the executable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="targetType"></param>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return GetApplicationExeVersion?.Invoke((string)parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("ProgramVersion converter ConvertBack not supported.");
    }
}
```

`GetApplicationExeVersion` is set to a method in another part of code, not needed there.

But I'm getting this Exception at runtime :

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:
'Unable to set' Binding 'on property' V1 'of type' MultiBinding '.
A 'Binding' can only be defined on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject. '
```

Am I in the rigth way or it is not possible to do it ?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Check out the [How to bind multiple values to a single WPF TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552853/how-to-bind-multiple-values-to-a-single-wpf-textblock)

Comment: Thank you, but @neelesh bodgal, I'm using the QuickConverter library   https://github.com/JohannesMoersch/QuickConverter  and I'd do it with this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can.
If you want to add a value as a result of a `System.Windows.Data.Binding` (or `System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding` etc.), you have to use one of the `P0`...`P9` properties of the `QuickConverter.MultiBinding`, as they *only* accept binding expressions. The `V0`...`V9` properties *only* accept constant values, no binding expressions.

```
<TextBlock Text="{qc:MultiBinding '$V0 + \' v\' + $P0',
 V0={x:Static resx:Resources.String225},
 P0={Binding Converter={StaticResource ProgramVersionConverter}, ConverterParameter='myParameter'}}"/>
```